# discord.js How do i make a bot talk in a specific channel

Tags: chat, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm making a announcement command where when a admin does -announce (text) it will announce it into the channel called announcement, How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard implementation, you can do it as follows

```
  bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith('-announce') && message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
        let announceChannel = bot.channels.get('YOUR ChannelID')
        if(!announceChannel) return
        announceChannel.send(message.content.substr(10,message.content.length))  //10 its length of you command
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting channel by name:

```
const Channel = client.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "announcements");
```

`client.channels` is a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection).

Sending the message using `.send()` method of [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel):

```
Channel.send("your announcement here");
```